# React-native build fails for android (IOException: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml)

Tags: android, react-native

I am building a react project (Android App). I followed react installation steps here [Setting up the development environment](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup) . Then i started the server using `npx react-native start` and while running `npx react-native run-android` I am getting following error

> IOException: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-3.xml
> java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
> IOException: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
> java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
> IOException: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-1.xml
> java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
> IO exception while downloading manifest:
> java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:installDebug'.

> Failed to find Build Tools revision 28.0.3